# Find initial values $y_0$ such that the solution of a non-linear system $Y'=f(Y)$, $Y(0)=y_0$ globally exists or explodes in finite time

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonlinear-system

Please consider $$\left\{\begin{matrix}Y'&=&f(Y)\\Y(0)&=&y_0\end{matrix}\right.\tag{1}$$ with $$f(u,v):=\begin{pmatrix}+2u-v-u^2v\\-2u+v+u^2v\end{pmatrix}\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;y_0:=\begin{pmatrix}u_0\\v_0\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^2$$ I want to show that

1. For all $u_0$, there is a $v_0$ such that the solution $Y$ of $(1)$ globally exists
2. For all $u_0$, there is a $v_0$ such that the solution $Y$ of $(1)$ explodes in finite time

---

I know that all that is somehow related to the zeros of $f$ and the eigenvalues of $-f'$. We've got $$A:=-f'(u,v)=\begin{pmatrix}-2+2uv&+1+u^2\\+2-2uv&-1-u^2\end{pmatrix}$$ So, the eigenvalues of $A$ are given by $$\sigma(A)=\left\{0,2uv-u^2-3\right\}$$ Moreover, $$f^{-1}(\left\{0\right\})=\left\{(u,v) : v=\frac{2u}{1+u^2}\right\}$$ However, all theorems I know so far require that all eigenvalues are positive, but here they are all non-positive.

Is there some clever way, to show (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the two entries of $f(u,v)$ is zero for every $(u,v)$ hence $u(t)+v(t)=u_0+v_0$ for every $t$ and $u'=A_{u_0+v_0}(u)$ where, for every $c$, $$A_c(x)=3x-c(1+x^2)+x^3.$$ Fix some $u_0$.

- Let $v_0=\dfrac{2u_0}{1+u_0^2}$, then $A_{u_0+v_0}(u_0)=0$ hence $(u(t),v(t))$ is defined globally (and constant).
- Let $c_0$ such that $A_{c_0}(x)\gt0$ for every $x\geqslant u_0$ and let $v_0=c_0-u_0$. Then $t\mapsto u(t)$ is increasing to $+\infty$ and, after some time $t_0$, $u(t)$ is so large that $u(t)\geqslant1$ and $u'(t)\geqslant\frac12u^3(t)$. Thus, $$\frac1{u(t_0)^2}-\frac1{u(t)^2}\geqslant t-t_0,$$ for every $t\geqslant t_0$ such that $u(t)$ is well defined. This implies that $u$ explodes at most at time $$t_0+\frac1{u(t_0)^2}.$$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Comment: In any case: Do we need $u(t)$ or $v(t)$ to be non-negative for $t>0$?

Comment: Sorry? I do not get what you mean.

Comment: What I mean is that I'm unsure whether or not $u$ and $v$ need to be non-negative, if $(u,v)$ is a solution of $(1)$.

Comment: Of course not, look at the picture.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with this kind of picture. What's the mathematical reason?

Comment: "I'm not familiar with this kind of picture" Hugh?! You better be, as soon as possible... "whether or not u and v need to be non-negative" Plenty of solutions fail this condition, some others satisfy it.

Comment: Okay, I think if we choose $u_0=0$ we've got $$u'(0)=-v_0<0$$ for any $v_0>0$. Since $u(0)=u_0$, $u$ should be negative on $(0,\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$.

Comment: Could you please explain why $u'=A_{u_0+v_0}(u)$? From (1) we've got $u'=2u-v-u^2v$. So, we would have $$A_{u_0+v_0}(u)=3u+\underbrace{(u_0+v_0)}_{\equiv u+v}(1+u^2)+u^3=2u-v-u^2v$$ and would be left with $$2u+2v+2u^2v+2u^3=0$$ which holds iff $u=-v$.

Comment: The explanation lies in the mistakes in your computations: indeed $u_0+v_0=u+v$ hence $$A_{u_0+v_0}(u)=3u-(u_0+v_0)(1+u^2)+u^3=3u-(u+v)(1+u^2)+u^3=2u-v-vu^2.$$

Comment: Sorry, I've mistakenly seen a "$+$" before $c$.

Comment: I think you've made a mistake. For $v_0=u_0(3+u_0^2)/(1+u_0^2)$ we have $A_{u_0+v_0}(u_0)=-u_0(u_0^2+1)\ne 0$ for all $u_0\ne 0$. I think we should choose $$v_0:=\frac{2u_0}{1+u_0^2}$$ instead.

Comment: And quite right you are. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: Hint: $u'(0)=0\iff v'(0)=0$.

Comment: I don't get what you do in the second case. Why is $u'(t)\ge\frac{1}{2}u^3(t)$ for all $t\ge t_0$? And where do you use this fact?

Comment: Maybe we should state, that after some finite time $t_0$, $$u(t)\ge c_0+1\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge t_0.$$ Moreover, we should require, that $c_0\ge 0$. This implies that $$u'\ge u^2+2c+3>u^2$$ on $[t_0,T_\max)$. Since $$u^2(\xi)<u'(\xi)=\frac{u(t)-u(t_0)}{t-t_0}\;\;\;\text{for some }\xi=\xi(t,t_0)\in (t_0,t)$$ we've got $$u(t)-u(t_0)>u^2(\xi)(t-t_0)\ge (c_0+1)(t-t_0)>t-t_0$$ hence $$t_0-u(t_0)>t-u(t)\to \infty\;\;\;\text{for }t\to\infty$$

Comment: No, not necessarily.